# How does sklearn.feature_selection.SelectFwe work?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics, feature-selection

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFwe, f_regression
from sklearn import __version__ #1.0.2
```

I have this example dataset:

```
X = np.array([
    [3,0,2,1],
    [7,3,0,5],
    [4,2,5,1],
    [6,2,7,3],
    [3,2,5,2],
    [6,1,1,4]
])
y = np.array([2,9,2,4,5,9])
```

The `f_regression(X, y)` function returns two arrays:

```
(array([ 4.68362124,  0.69456469,  2.59714175, 27.64721141]),
 array([0.09643779, 0.45148854, 0.18234859, 0.00626275]))
```

The first one contains the F-statistic for the 4 features of my dateset, the second one contains the p-values associated with the F-statistic.

Now suppose I want to extract the features with a p-value lower than 0.15; what I expect is that the first and last features are selected. I would like to use `SelectFwe` ([here the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectFwe.html)) to perform this step, so:

```
SelectFwe(f_regression, alpha=.15).fit(X, y).get_support()
```

Unfortunately it returns `array([False, False, False,  True])`, meaning that only the last feature is selected.

Why does it happen? Did I misunderstand how `SelectFwe` works? Probably the following picture is helpful:

[image]

The code I used to produce the plot:

```
plt.plot(
    np.linspace(0,1,101),
    [SelectFwe(f_regression, alpha=alpha).fit(X, y).get_support().sum() for alpha in np.linspace(0,1,101)]
)

plt.xlabel("alpha")
plt.ylabel("selected features")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Puzzling; and it can be even worse, for `alpha=0.5` it returns `array([ True, False, False, True])`...! Where does the plot come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/baf828ca126bcb2c0ad813226963621cafe38adb/sklearn/feature_selection/_univariate_selection.py#L851-L854), the alpha is divided by the number of features:

```py
    def _get_support_mask(self):
        check_is_fitted(self)

        return self.pvalues_ < self.alpha / len(self.pvalues_)
```

This is because the class is considering "family-wise error" rate, which is

> the probability of making **one or more** false discoveries

([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family-wise_error_rate), my emph).  You can use instead [`SelectFpr`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectFpr.html), "false positive rate" test, which works exactly the same but [doesn't divide](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/baf828ca126bcb2c0ad813226963621cafe38adb/sklearn/feature_selection/_univariate_selection.py#L695-L698) by the number of features.  See also [Issue1007](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1007).